# How to get rid of $0 in Swift closure?

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Test {
    func someMethod() {}

    init(closure:(Test)->Void) {
        closure(self)
    }
}
```

I can call init like this in another method of another class (1)

```
Test {
    $0.someMethod()
}
```

or like this (2)

```
Test { t in
    t.someMethod()
}
```

Is there any possible solution that will allow to write exact same thing without "$0" or "t"? I would like to get this code (3)

```
Test {
    someMethod()
}
```

Behaviour must be exactly as in (1) or (2).

Is it possible? Maybe not with closures, but with some other Swift feature?

I want to do something like this Kotlin type-safe builder: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html

Comment: You cannot actually make the calls you have listed, if `someMethod` is an instance method of Test. Your code will not compile if it consists of the class Test as you have written it, plus either of the initializations you have written.

Comment: Well, of course, (1) or (2) has to be inside some other method. It does compile and works great, except I have to write tons of "$0".

Comment: Seems to me you are just asking Swift not to be Swift but to be some other language. It isn't.

Comment: Of course it is not. I'm asking whether I can execute closure in the context of "Test" instance.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at, but it might be useful to you to know that an instance method in Swift is actually a curried class method whose first parameter is the instance.

Comment: A closure as per definition is executed in the context of its declaration.

Comment: That is correct, that is why I'm asking also about other Swift features that can emulate this behavior. I've looked everywhere but I'm far from being Swift expert in any way so maybe I've missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're after, but I wonder whether this little bit of voodoo might be useful to you:

```
    class Test {
        var name : String
        init(_ name:String) {self.name = name}
        func someMethod() { println("Hi, my name is \(name)") }
    }
    let f = Test.someMethod
    let t1 = Test("matt")
    let t2 = Test("bealex")
    f(t1)() // Hi, my name is matt
    f(t2)() // Hi, my name is bealex
```

Point is that `f(t1)` is itself a function which, when called, sends `someMethod` to the instance `t1`. You might be able to get some mileage out of that.

Comment: This is a very interesting thought. Thanks! Will think into it.

Comment: Better you than me. I'm hopelessly befuddled at this point. :)

Comment: Sure. I'm searching for possible solutions for two days now. You guys are my last hope of inventing something before WWDC :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that would be impossible in Swift, as swift is missing some kind of *dynamic extension function* feature.

In swift the only way to extend is to define a new function (or whatever) like:

```
extension Type {
  func function() {}
}
```

So no possibility to define extensions on the fly, as far as I know.

So what we really are missing is something like this: (Wishlist for next version of Swift?)

**Code below will not work, example of how it could work**

```
class Test {
    var aVar = 0
    func someMethod() {}

    // Param declares function as an extension on type Test!
    class func initialize(closure: Test.()->Void) -> Test {
        let instance = Test()
        instance.closure() 
        return instance
    }
} 

// And it would be possible to do:
Test.initialize {
    self.someMethod()
    aVar = 1234 // With or without self, with or without self...
}
```

Once again, not working. But oh, how nice it would be...

UPDATE: Code was a bit of, fixed now.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it is done in Kotlin (and, possibly, some other languages) and I would love to see something like this in "Swift 2". Trying to imitate this I ended up with tons of "$0" at the best.

Comment: But I think the solutions in your own question is the closets you could get to this in Swift. But who knows, maybe someone will post some amazing stuff here any second :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to satisfy type checker. So typechecker wants you to write closure that is `Test -> Void`. If you don't use `Test` parameter you can ignore it like this:

```
Test { _ in someAnotherMethod() }
```

**EDIT:** I completely misunderstand your question @bealex. Now I have another solution but it is ugly and It have some limitations. Here is the code

```
class Test {

    init (_ f: Test -> () -> Void) {
        f(self)()
    }

    func doSomething() {
        println("Hello world")
    }
}

let test = Test(Test.doSomething)
```

This only works for the methods that take no (or rather `void`) parameters. For how this works: Swift instance methods are curried functions that is the first parameter is `self`. [Link](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)

For instance methods that take one parameter we can write swap method that swaps the function's parameter order.

```
func swap<A, B, C>(f: A -> B -> C) -> B -> A -> C {
    return { b in { a in f(a)(b)} }
}
```

Now we can write

```
class Test {

    init (_ f: Test -> Void) {
        f(self)
    }

    func doSomethingWithNumber(number: Int, str: String) {
        println("Hello planet \(number), \(str)")
    }
}


let test = Test(swap(Test.doSomethingWithNumber)(10, "Greetings"))
```

But this is more verbose than using plain `$0 and $1`. Anyway this is the another perspective.